# Save and Retrieve array of views in android

Tags: android, canvas, view, save, data-retrieval

In a canvas the user is able to create views like EditText, ImageViews and it is possible to drag and drop them inside the view. All these views are added to an arraylist on click of a button with below code:

```
for(int index=0; index<((ViewGroup)mDragLayer).getChildCount(); ++index) {
                    View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)mDragLayer).getChildAt(index);
                    elementList.add(nextChild);
}
```

While the user is on the same screen, it is possible to populate the same view with the help of `elementList` with below code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < elementList.size(); i++){
        mDragLayer.addView(elementList.get(i));
}
```

The question is, how can `elementList` be used at a later stage (relaunching after killing the app) to populate the view. I have tried to use shared preferences but failed.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can not persist views if Android system kills your app. Instead, you can persist a model that is needed to recreate those views. You can use `SharedPreferences` or a database for this.

Use activity or fragment callbacks to determine if there is a state that you need to recreate and then build your own logic for recreating the view hierarchy from the data that you stored before the app was killed. You can recreate everything, if needs to be very precise, you can even store a position of each view and then use those values in layout params to rebuild the UI.

Comment: what you mean is it is not possible to store textview information directly in shared preferences?

Comment: You can save textview information if you convert to String or String[] but no TextView object.

Comment: All view objects have the same lifecycle as enclosing activity or fragment has. Once activity is killed the whole view hierarchy is killed. You can persist data needed to recreate the view, it can be text, position, color, etc. but you can not persist the view itself, you will have to recreate it.

Comment: Now it's possible to persist views directly without any code. Check out [NxPreference](https://github.com/ErrorxCode/NxPreference) library.